# Stop execution of the getCurrentPosition method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using the getCurrentPosition method in Javascript. I would like to implement a button that stops the execution of the method "getCurrentPosition" when it's clicked. I tried with throw/try/catch blocks but it doesn't seem to work :

```
    try {
        $('#cancel').on("click", function() { 
            $.mobile.loading('hide'); 
            throw "stop";
        });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout : 30000 }); 
    }
    catch ( er ) { alert(er); return false; }
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible in JS ?
I had an idea but I don't know if it's possible to trigger a timeout with a JS method so that the getCurrentPosition breaks ?

Comment: It's supposed to be an asynchronous method so shouldn't stop rendering or anything but the w3 spec doesn't allow you to stop it once started. Do you just want to ignore the result if the button is clicked? The code you posted has no chance of working, events and asynch methods do not work that way.

Comment: When the button is clicked, I want to stop the execution of getCurrentPosition (with something similar to clearTimeout).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Solution:

Method **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition** is an asynchronous function so don't count on stopping it just like that.

You should instead use other function called: **[navigator.geolocation.watchPosition](http://www.thedotproduct.org/2010/04/example-of-navigator-geolocation-watchposition/)**. It works in the same way as getCurrentPosition but what make it usefull in your case is another function called **[navigator.geolocation.clearWatch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_clearwatch.htm)** and that function is used to stop watchPosition.

## Example:

```
geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
geoLoc.clearWatch(watchID);
```

Comment: Good thing to keep in mind: watchPosition will call the handler function every time the device position changes, as opposed to getCurrentPosition, which will call the function only once. This could cause unexpected issues in your program.